# Can I define an EC2 auto scale group with scaling policies without adding alarms to CloudWatch dashboard?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch, metric

I followed the instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html in order to have a CPUUtilization based auto scale group. i noticed that the alarms created by mon-put-metric-alarm create alarms that are listed on the cloudwatch dashboard. This means that on low cpu utlilization I always have a metric in ALARM state. Can I hide the auto scale metrics in the CloudWatch web interface?

Comment: "This means that on low cpu utlilization I always have a metric in ALARM state." - I have the same annoyance, which lead me here. Sorry to see there's no good solutions yet.

Comment: Yes, I checked it with the premium support and they only gave workarounds. They kind of admitted that the current alarm dashboard is pretty useless once you have auto scaling.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that even three years later this is still an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question (+1) - I'm not aware of any option to *hide the auto scale metrics* in the [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) web interface and the respective [PutMetricAlarm API action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html) doesn't feature a related option either.

While your use case is sound, the AWS team usually follows the [Minimum viable product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) approach when implementing a new service initially, and despite steadily adding additional features later on, they still tend to obey the [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) when choosing worthwhile features, so I doubt that your understandable request will be implemented anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has now added this feature, there is a check box next to the search var to hide all AutoScaling alarms.